# Bad code to handle image upload

Tags: php, network-file-transfer

I'm using this form to submit articles into the database:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="add.php">

  <input name="title" type="text">
  <input name="image" type="file">
  <textarea name="text"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="go" value="Spremi">

</form>
```

```
include ("database.php"); 
$upload_path = "files/images/";
$prefix= date("Hi-mdY")."-";

$file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $file_name);
$file_name = str_replace('_', '-', $file_name);
$file_name = strtolower($file_name);

$upload_path = $upload_path . basename($prefix.$file_name);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $upload_path);

$final_file_name = ("/files/images/".$prefix.$file_name);
$date=date("Y.m.d");

$sql="INSERT INTO articles (title, image_link,  text, date) VALUES ('$_POST[title]', '$final_file_name', '$_POST[text]', '$date')"
if (mysql_query($sql)){
    echo "done";
} else {
    echo "error<br>" . mysql_error();
}
```

And here is the problem:

One of my friends told me that the PHP code in `add.php` is incorrect.

This is working for me, but can someone correct the code please.

### EDIT:

Thanks guys, I've corrected the code :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">

  <input name="title" type="text">
  <input name="image" type="file">
  <textarea name="text"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit">

</form>
```

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['go'])){
    include ("database.php"); 
    $upload_path = "files/images/";
    $prefix= date("Hi-mdY")."-";

    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace('_', '-', $file_name);
    $file_name = strtolower($file_name);

    $upload_path = $upload_path . basename($prefix.$file_name);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $upload_path);

    $final_file_name = ("/files/images/".$prefix.$file_name);

    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $text=$_POST['text'];
    $date=date("Y.m.d");

    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
    $final_file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($final_file_name);
    $text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);

    $sql="INSERT INTO articles (title, image_link,  text, date) VALUES ('$title', '$final_file_name', '$text', '$date')";
    if (mysql_query($sql)){
      echo "done";
    } else {
      echo "error<br>" . mysql_error();
    }
  }
?>
```

Now it's good?

Comment: I would be able to upload a script and take over your server :)

Comment: Use MySQLi as MySQL is deprecated http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php using prepared statements will also help secure your form http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php these type of forms are available for download if you google upload forms. You should also create a whitelist for file types allowed

Answer (score 10):

There are quite few things to note in your code.

First of all, you are using deprecated `$HTTP_POST_FILES` where as you should use `$_FILES`

You are not using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function in your query variables and therefore are vulnerable to **[sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)** which is caused through poor sql queries.

You are not checking whether or not the submit button was clicked, you should wrap your entire code in between:

```
if (isset($_POST['go'])){
  // your code
}
```

Comment: just that is incorrect?

Comment: @user554943: It is correct otherwise and will work but you should also consider the points i have told above.